# Haskell: Control.Category.Monoidal: inverse of associate, idl and idr

Tags: haskell, category-theory

`Control.Category.Associative` declares the morphism `associate`:

```
class Bifunctor p k k k => Associative k p where
    associate :: k (p (p a b) c) (p a (p b c))
```

But, as I understand monoidal categories, the associator should be an isomorphism. Where is its inverse? 
`Control.Categor.Monoidal` doesn't declare it either, just the left and right unitor components (`idl` and `idr`), and also omits their inverses.

Is there a possibility to get the inverses from these morphisms in a canonical way that I'm overlooking, or why are the inverses omitted?

Comment: `category-extras` has been deprecated for a while. Have you looked at [`Associative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Category-Associative.html) from the `categories` replacement package? This package also has [`Monoidal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Category-Monoidal.html) with inverses.

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not know it was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the inverse is defined by the class [`Coassociative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.51.3/docs/Control-Category-Associative.html), and it is probably that way just for more granularity and generality.

Comment: The type is right, but isn't usually "Co" something different from "inverse"?

Comment: Ah good point.  We probably need some sort of law that relates the two...

Comment: If that is true, than the inverses for `idl` and `idr` are in `Comonoidal`. The Documentation says:  This type class is also (ab)used for the inverse operations needed for a strict (co)monoidal category. A strict (co)monoidal category is one that is both Monoidal and Comonoidal and satisfies the following laws:

Comment: … But according to my humble understanding of category theory, this is nonsense. The associator and the unitors should _always_ have an inverse. And Wikipedia says: A **strict monoidal category** is one for which the natural isomorphisms α, λ and ρ are identities.

Comment: You're probably right. I think you should probably talk to Ed directly https://github.com/ekmett/category-extras

Comment: Your answer helped me to find where the inverses are, but I also learned that I was asking about a deprecated Package, which was even more helpful. So, should I accept your answer or what? I don't know.

Comment: Benjamin, who cares?  ;-)  I guess it's a (very weak) signal to future searchers about whether they will find something useful here...